# Combine two data by every 3rd row

Tags: dplyr, merge, aggregate

I have the following two data frames:

```
df<- structure(t(data.frame(x=1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10)))
df2<- structure(data.frame(x= rep(30, times=10)))
```

I am looking to combine the two data frames so that one row of `df2` is inserted into every third spot on `df`. So the final data frame should look like:

```
df3<- structure(t(data.frame(x=1,1,30,2,2,30,3,3,30,4,4,30,5,5,30,6,6,30,7,7,30,8,8,30,9,9,30,10, 10,30)))
```

This could be done by making a grouping variable for each data frame. Like:

```
df$group<- rep(1:10, times=2) %>% arrange(group)

df2$group<- rep(1:10)
```

And then merging based on the group, but the order of my rows in `df` is important and cannot be switched around.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by joining the two data frames together with a customer sort order.

Something like the following:

```r
df<- structure(t(data.frame(x=1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10)))
df2<- structure(data.frame(x= rep(30, times=10)))

# current row orders
df = df %>%
  mutate(row_number = 1:nrow(df),
         source = "df")
df2 = df2 %>%
  mutate(row_number = 1:nrow(df2),
         source = "df2")

# prep customer sorters
df2 = df2 %>% mutate(row_number = 2 * row_number + 0.5)

# attend and sort
df3 = rbind(df, df2) %>%
  arrange(row_number)

# remove extra columns
df3 = df3 %>%
  select(-row_number, -source)
```

Most of the cleverness happens in the customer sorter: `row_number = 2 * row_number + 0.5` of `df2`.

- Adding 0.5 ensure that the `df2` rows occur between `df` rows.
- Multiplying by 2 means there will be two rows from `df` between each row in `df2`
- Getting the current row orders means that row orders for `df` and `df2` are preserved.